# phpseclib read() takes previous command output

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am using `phpseclib` to copy file from remote host to localhost. Before I proceed further, I play around with the interactive shell so that I could understand the behavior. I am confused with the behavior in my current code which seems its `read()` function displays the result of previous command as well. See below:

```
if (!$ssh->login("myusername", "mypwd")) { 
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("cd /tmp; ls *.csv1\n");
$output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ansi->appendString($output);
echo $output = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($ansi->getScreen()));

$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("cd /tmp; ls *.txt\n");
$txt_output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ansi->appendString($txt_output);
echo $txt_output = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($ansi->getScreen()));
```

Below is the output:

```
cd /tmp; ls *.csv1 ls: *.csv1: No such file or directory [user@host tmp]#

cd /tmp; ls *.csv1 ls: *.csv1: No such file or directory [user@host tmp]#cd /tmp; ls *.txt ls: *.txt: No such file or directory [user@host tmp]#
```

It seems to me when my code process second command, it will take the first command as well. How do I proceed the second command in fresh mode? I appreciate the reply, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$ansi->loadString()`. `$ansi->appendString()` appends, as the name implies.

Comment: For some reason, I have changed my approach so I am not using the `ANSI` stuff at the moment, however will keep this as notes. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

So after some time playing more with the code and I start realizing one pattern. It seems to me that I need to re-initialize the `ANSI` every time I want to use it.

```
$ansi = new File_ANSI(); // <== NOTE THIS LINE
$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("cd /tmp; ls *.csv1\n");
$output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ansi->appendString($output);
echo $output = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($ansi->getScreen()));

$ansi = new File_ANSI(); // <== INITIALIZE AGAIN TO OUTPUT
$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("cd /tmp; ls *.txt\n");
$txt_output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ansi->appendString($txt_output);
echo $txt_output = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($ansi->getScreen()));
```

And the output will come as below and you can do whatever you want:

```
cd /tmp; ls *.csv1 ls: *.csv1: No such file or directory [user@host tmp]#

cd /tmp; ls *.txt ls: *.txt: No such file or directory [user@host tmp]#
```

Hopefully this would help somebody out there.